# Possibility of bounding one functional by another functional (under certain constraints)

Tags: inequalities, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

Suppose that we consider a class of $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ functions $h$ such that $h$ can be expressed as a difference of two cumulative distribution functions $F$ and $G$ (whose corresponding densities are $f \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ and $g \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}_+)$, respectively), i.e., $h(x) = F(x) - G(x)$. I am wondering if it is possible to upper bound $$I_1 := \int_0^\infty |h(x)|^2\, \mathrm{d}x $$ by some functionals of $$I_2 := \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2_+} \frac{h(x)\cdot h(y)}{x+y} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y.$$ For instance, would it be possible to upper bound $I_1$ by some polynomial function of $I_2$？ Note that $I_2$ is non-negative since $$I_2 = \int_0^{\infty} |\hat{h}(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi$$ where $\hat{h}(\xi)$ denotes the Laplace transform of $h(x)$. I know that without the constraint that $h$ must be the difference of two CDFs, then there is no hope to achieve the desired bound, so I am hoping this restriction can make a difference (we may further assume that the two densities $f$ and $g$ have the same mean value $\mu > 0$, leading to a further constraint that $\int_0^\infty h(x)\,\mathrm{d} x = 0$). I appreciate any help or pointers to literature!

---

Edit: I forgot to mention that the second moments of $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be bounded (by some fixed finite constant), and if we assume that the two densities $f$ and $g$ have the same mean value $\mu > 0$, it means that the mean value is pre-fixed and hence cannot tend to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course not, even if the two distributions have the same mean.

Indeed, for $n>1$ and all real $x$ let
$$F(x):=F_n(x):=1(x\ge n),\quad 
G(x):=G_n(x):=\frac{1(x\ge n-\sqrt n)+1(x\ge n+\sqrt n)}2. $$
Then $F$ and $G$ are cdf's of distributions with the same mean $n$, and
$$h(x)=h_n(x):=\frac{1(n\le x<n+\sqrt n)-1(n-\sqrt n\le x<n)}2.$$
So, letting $n\to\infty$, we get
$$I_1=\sqrt n/2\to\infty,$$
$$I_2\le\frac14\int_{n-\sqrt n}^{n+\sqrt n}
\int_{n-\sqrt n}^{n+\sqrt n}\frac{dx\,dy}{2(n-\sqrt n)}
=\frac{n}{2(n-\sqrt n)}\to\frac12.$$

So, the inequality
$$I_1\le H(I_2)$$
cannot hold for any locally bounded function $H$.

Comment: Thank you Professor, but when I say "have the same mean value" I really mean that they have the common "fixed"' (and hence finite) mean value. I have edited my post correspondingly.

Comment: @FeiCao : You may have wanted to say "fixed", but in actuality you said "have the same mean value". Two quantities can of course be the same without being fixed. You should not edit your post to invalidate a valid answer. So, please roll back your edit.

Comment: So sorry for not being too precise at first, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Also, the $F$ and $G$ do not have continuous "densities"...

Comment: @FeiCao : By approximation, smoothness conditions never matter in problems like this.